# Why is the Stack Exchange Flair Icon Generic Instead of Showing the User Icon?

Tags: support, flair

Until a little over a day ago the icon that showed on the Stack Exchange flair was the same as my site avatar. But now its showing some generic blue icon.

I wrote support to ask:

> I was wondering why today my flair for StackExchange profile
> https://stackexchange.com/users/3038649 which is
> https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3038649.png suddenly changed from
> my normal image to some generic blue star?

And they responded:

> That's a really good question. Take it to meta:
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Not exactly sure how meta is supposed to handle this matter but based on them thinking it would be good to ask here, I am asking here. Why isn't the site icon showing up on the flair anymore?

### Update

I went ahead and connected my email address for SE to my gravatar account and on the Area 51 site it shows correctly now. The flair is still showing the old one but the system states it can take up to 24-36 hours to update, so we'll see if that change corrects it. Thank you for the answer and will accept as soon as the flair reflect the correct image so we know it resolved it. Thanks again.

### Confirmed

I wanted to thank and accept the answer and let you know that the flair did indeed update to the proper image now and its reflected through the site where it calls it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shows the blue avatar, because that's the avatar of your [Area51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/96231/gardian), which has the most reputation out of all your accounts on the network. Change the avatar on Area51 and your flair will do the same.

The avatar on Area51 is your gravatar, so you might need to change your email there, or add the existing email to your gravatar account.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate that. Its odd that the site had my avatar that I have on all the sites but now it has no picture. When did they decide to switch to gravatar on that site or has it always been that way?